# How to get the rows of last occurrence of a streak in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'y':['a','a','b','c','b','b','a','b','c','c']})
```

How can we return a dataframe like the following

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,5,6,7,9],'y':['a','b','c','b','a','b','c']})
```

[image]

Is there an efficient way using column operations instead of looping through each rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find everytime a value is different that the next, so comparing to the next is sufficient:

```
mask = df1['y'].ne(df1['y'].shift(-1))
df2 = df1[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
   x  y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  5  b
4  6  a
5  7  b
6  9  c
```

Comment: This solution took 12ms for 500K rows. Although Quang's solution worked it took 14s.

Comment: @Daniel....could you try a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149499/how-to-cut-unsorted-time-series-data-into-bins-with-a-minimum-interval

Answer (score 2):

A classic application of `cumsum` to find consecutive blocks:

```
df1.groupby(df1['y'].ne(df1['y'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).last()
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  5  b
4  6  a
5  7  b
6  9  c
```