# How to cut unsorted time-series data into bins with a minimum interval?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe like this

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1341, 1.13421, 1.13433, 1.13412, 1.13435, 1.13447, 1.13459, 1.13452, 1.13471, 1.1348, 1.13496,1.13474,1.13483,1.1349,1.13502,1.13515,1.13526,1.13512]})
```

How can we split this series to get the following output such that the minimum difference is at least 0.0005

```
x['output'] =  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

[image]

Comment: "How can we split this series to get the following output such that the minimum difference is at least 0.0005": the difference to what? Between any two numbers of the sub-series?

Comment: Does computational efficiency matter to your case? Also, what are the characteristics of the data? (There might be several sub-lists that satisfy the condition, e.g. if your list is (1, 1.0001, 2, 2.0001)

Comment: Efficiency is important. I want to apply this to 1M rows. The subset should be in the original list. In this case the answer should be [1.1341,1.13471,1.13526] because 1.1341 - 1.13471 = 0.00061 and 1.13471 - 1.13526 = 0.00055. Difference need not be always positive.

Comment: 1.13512 - 1.13483 ?

Comment: Is not clear to me why there is a 1 for 1.13410? It is because 1.3410 - 1.3421 > 0.0005?

Comment: @DanielMesejo it is 1.13410. I corrected it and assume the first number's output is always 1.

Comment: @splash58 this is a sequential problem and we have to start from the first number and find the next available number(say z) which is 0.0005 greater or less than the first number and continue the same logic form z. If we use loops it would be far easy but I am looking for a pandas column operation type solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a vectorized way to do this, so you probably need to loop through the values.

```
x = x.assign(output=0)  # Initialize all the output values to zero.
x['output'].iat[0] = 1
threshold = 0.0005
prior_val = x['a'].iat[0]
for n, val in enumerate(x['a']):
    if abs(val - prior_val) >= threshold:
        x['output'].iat[n] = 1
        prior_val = val  # Reset to new value found that exceeds threshold.
```

Comment: I thought so but was looking for confirmation.

Comment: @Alexander if you run it with x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.00001, 1.2, 1.00001]}), you will select all three numbers, even though two numbers are the same. Or maybe I misunderstood (and consequently misedited) the question?

Comment: @Gabriel I just rolled back that edit.  I don't believe it was the intent of the OP as one can infer by observing the given `output` in the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try with the most of vectorization and a recursive function.

The recursive function build a one line dataframe send to the caller and concatenate at the end of the main function.

It uses the nullable integer type added to pandas in version 0.24.

**Edit**: This solution is tenth times slower than the one with loops. You should not use it.

```py
import pandas as pd


def find_next_step(df, initial_value, threshold):
    try:
        following_index = (
            df.loc[lambda x: (x['a'] - initial_value).abs() >= threshold]
            .loc[:, 'a']
            .index[0]
        )
    except IndexError:
        return []
    to_append = find_next_step(
        df.loc[following_index + 1:, :], x.loc[following_index, 'a'], threshold
    )
    to_append.append(
        pd.DataFrame({'output': [1]}, index=[following_index], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
    )
    return to_append


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1341, 1.13421, 1.13433, 1.13412, 1.13435, 1.13447, 1.13459, 1.13452, 1.13471, 1.1348, 1.13496,1.13474,1.13483,1.1349,1.13502,1.13515,1.13526,1.13512]})
    output_list = find_next_step(x.iloc[1:, :], x.loc[:, 'a'].iloc[0], 0.0005)
    output_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'output': [1]}, index=[0], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype()))
    output_series = pd.concat(
        [x, pd.concat(output_list).sort_index()], axis='columns'
    ).assign(output=lambda x: x['output'].fillna(0))
```

It works on your example, this prints:

```
          a  output
0   1.13410       1
1   1.13421       0
2   1.13433       0
3   1.13412       0
4   1.13435       0
5   1.13447       0
6   1.13459       0
7   1.13452       0
8   1.13471       1
9   1.13480       0
10  1.13496       0
11  1.13474       0
12  1.13483       0
13  1.13490       0
14  1.13502       0
15  1.13515       0
16  1.13526       1
17  1.13512       0
```

Comment: I tried running this on a larger dataframe to test timings, but hit max recursion depth.  This solution is _much_ slower than a simple loop.

Comment: I should have test the timings. It is 10 times slower. :-( I edit my post.